# is there a way to retrieve ad cost for an ASIN using Amazon Advertising API?

Tags: php, api, amazon-advertising-api

For last couple of days I am digging into Amazon advertising api and looking for a solution to find advertising cost using ASIN and Amazon Advertising API. The closest I could find is this [Campaign Report](https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/reference/reports#Campaigns-reports).

It returns a list of campaigns with campaign id and cost per campaign. But Ideally, I would like to pass parameters like ASIN and a date or a date range, to retrieve the advertising cost.

Comment: I don't think there is. Browsing their API documentation there is no such method to use ASIN. One way to work around this is to make a new Ad Group for each ASIN (a pain but that is what I do). https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/v2/reference/campaigns

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the reply. This question was posted long ago and I even forgot about it lol. Luckily I found a way - There is a report named sponsoredProducts and it gives out costs data for a particular date for all the products. You can also get historic data for last 60 days or so with this report. I saved the historic data and added a cron to get the daily data. At last it as all php-mysql thing and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found a way to deal with this problem. There are different reports available with the api and **sponsoredProducts** solved my problem. It returns asin, impression, clicks and cost etc for a particular date.

I also used a github library, which made it very easy to work with the Advertising api. I'd surely recommend using this one -

https://github.com/amzn/amazon-advertising-api-php-sdk#requestreport